# Remove scrollbar thumb handle from listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a list which shows a thumb style scroll handler style on the right side.

How can I remove it?

Thanks

Like :

[image]

Comment: can you post ListView in xml file code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Listview Xml Attribute

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false" >
</ListView>
```

android:fastScrollEnabled="false"

make `false` above attribute may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
android:scrollbars="none" in your xml file where you have mentioned your listview code.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scrollbars="none"`

So an example ListView would be:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```